# .Net assembly adds superfluous AND when setting bool to TRUE?

Tags: c#, assembly, clr

The following code written in C# in VS2010 for .Net 4.0:

```
bool b = false;
```

has the following disassembly:

```
XOR EDX,EDX
MOV DWORD PTR[EBP-3Ch],EDX
```

which makes perfect sense.

However, the following code:

```
bool b = true;
```

has the following disassembly:

```
MOV EAX,1
AND EAX,0FFh
MOV DWORD PTR[EBP-3Ch],EAX
```

What is the purpose of the `AND` operation? Why not just `MOV EAX,1`?

```
Line | EAX
-----------
   1 | 0x01
   2 | 0x01 & 0xFF = 0x01
   3 | 0xFF
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems like it would clear the high bytes of EAX, but `MOV EAX, 1` should do that anyway..

Comment: How are you even finding the hardware assembly for a CLR source?

Comment: I'm just confused as to why you care about this at all? I mean, i nit-pick my compiled IL all the time.. but what the runtime does with the compiled IL is the runtime's business.

Comment: @Blorgbeard Yes - woops. Fixed now.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Ctrl+Alt+D to show disassembly while debugging.

Comment: @caesay I was just comparing what goes on under the hood with `b1=true;b1=false;` versus `b1=true;b2=!b1;` versus `b2=!(b1=true);` and stumbled across this.

Comment: @Ozzah, Cool, I never knew that....

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the `and 0xff` is truncation to 8-bit bool.  I don't know nearly enough about the internals to be sure, but I suspect `bool b = true` is becoming something like `bool b = int(1)` which is then becoming `bool b = bool(int(1))` and it's that coercion to bool causes the `and 0xff`.  I see similar things in x86 epilogs of C++ functions returning bool (e.g. ending in `test; setal`) rather than just returning an arbitrary nonzero value.

This is the kind of code that a peephole optimizer would fix...

Comment: I see. But wouldn't it make more sense to take the value from the AH or AL registers instead of EAX then? That way the value is already 8-bit and the computer doesn't need to truncate 32-bits to 8-bit.

Comment: The destination is a DWORD though, an 8-bit register wouldn't fill it.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
bool a = true;
bool c = false;
```

generates this IL assembly:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_0002:  stloc.0     
IL_0003:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0004:  stloc.1
```

You can see in the intermediate language, the code is essentially the same.   How the jitter is translating that, or why it would not do effectively parallel code for the two is very bizarre.

(I put this as an answer instead of a comment just so I could format the discussion to be readable.)

Answer (score 0):

The AND opcode will also cause some of the status FLAGS to be set (OF, CF, SF, ZF, and PF) according to the Intel manual (http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).  Without the context of the rest of the instructions in the function its pretty hard to guess what the purpose is.

Comment: `bool b = true` doesn't really seem complicated enough to necessitate flags in the CPU. I don't see why there should be any asymmetry between `bool b = true` and `bool b = false`.

Comment: It may be for instructions that are executed later.

Comment: I never learned x86 family assembly language, since my assembly days are long past.  But older processors, such as the 6502 would definitely set different flags for a zero value than they would for others, which could affect subsequent branch instructions.